# Use a MessageBox to get a user input?

Tags: c#

Sorry for the strange suggestion in the title...

I'm looking to try and get a single piece of information from a user, and I was wondering if there was a variant of `MessageBox` that would grab a single piece of data, like a number as a parameter for a list size.

```
int listSize = Convert.ToInt32(MessageBox.TextBox.Text);
```

I don't really want to go through the effort of creating a tiny form for this single purpose if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the VB.Net [InputBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox.aspx), directly from C#

```
string input = 
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("My Prompt", 
                                               "The Title", 
                                               "Desired Default", 
                                               -1, -1);
int listSize;
bool success = int.TryParse(input, out listSize);
```

You will probably need to add an appropriate reference to your project.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think they kept this thing around.

Comment: The VB.Net InputBox is there because VB.Net had an InputBox function, and the programmer base expected it.

Comment: So there is one?? Awesome! I'll try it out and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Yep.  Note, you will probably need to add an appropriate reference to your project.

Comment: Haha yeah that's probably a given :)